# Is it possible to make plugin extension hooks like WordPress actions in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm about to rewrite a highly modular CMS in Rust, so my question is if it's even possible to have the "core" application set up extension points (actions/hooks), which other plugins / crates is able to "tab" into.

[Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28003144/3973406) would suffice, but how would you do this in Rust? The architecture above uses a plugin registry and initiates each plugin's main method from the core by iterating over each of them. However in Rust, since you can't have a global "modules" variable in e.g. a plugin_registry lib crate, I guess this is not the correct thinking in Rust.

Is there a better and more flexible way to make "plugins" integrate seamlessly with a core application? For example, something like an event dispatcher like WordPress uses?

Comment: Shepmaster why would you downvote and close this? Very constructive, I learned a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Sure it's *possible* - Rust is Turing complete and all that. Something like [iron](https://github.com/iron/iron) has a "middleware" stack - perhaps that would give you a place to start investigating? Then you can ask specific, targeted question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm asking what the right approach would be to writeing a core application with extension points, from which 3rd party modules/crates/plugins would be able to hook into and add functionality, integrating seemsless ly with the core application.. Sorry for not being a rust expert and asking a stupid question

Comment: No offense intended, I just don't believe that the question *in it's current form* is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are all kinds of questions that are [not ideal to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Don't worry, it will take 4 more people to agree before the question is actually closed; maybe they will disagree with me.

Comment: I'll try to rewrite my question then. I'm pretty new to rust, but I really would love to know the "rust way" to make this kind of plugin structure

Comment: It has nothing to do with Rust or being an "expert" ^_^. I believe that if you asked the same question for any language here on SO it would merit the same response. As I see it, asking "how do I write a large program so that it has X and Y characteristics" goes far beyond the scope of SO questions and answers. A useful answer would have to cover so much ground. Again, this is all my opinion; others may agree with you.

Comment: Fair enough, however if you take a look at the url I linked to in the question, you'd see a pretty awesome answer, when I asked a similar question in Golang. That's exactly what I'm looking for - but the rust way of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Shepmaster said, this is a very general question; hence there are many ways to do what you want. And as already mentioned, too, [`iron`](https://github.com/iron/iron) is a great example of a modular framework.

However, I'll try to give a useful example of how one *could* implement such a plugin system. For the example I will assume, that there is some kind of main-crate that can load the plugins and "configure" the CMS. This means that the plugins aren't loaded dynamically!

---

## Structure

First, lets say we have four crates:

- `rustpress`: the big main crate with all WordPress-like functionality
- `rustpress-plugin`: needs to be used by plugin authors (is an own crate in order to avoid using a huge crate like `rustpress` for every plugin)
- `rustpress-signature`: here we create our plugin which will add a signature to each post
- `my-blog`: this will be the main executable that configures our blog and will run as a web server later

---

#### 1. The trait/interface

The way to go in Rust are `trait`s. You can compare them to interfaces from other languages. We will now design the `trait` for plugins which lives in `rustpress-plugin`:

```
pub trait Plugin {
    /// Returns the name of the plugin
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
    /// Hook to change the title of a post
    fn filter_title(&self, title: &mut String) {}
    /// Hook to change the body of a post
    fn filter_body(&self, body: &mut String) {}
}
```

Note that the `filter_*` methods already have a default implementation that does nothing (`{}`). This means that plugins don't have to override all methods if they only want to use one hook.

#### 2. Write our plugin

As I said we want to write a plugin that adds our signature to each posts body. To do that we will `impl` the trait for our own type (in `rustpress-signature`):

```
extern crate rustpress_plugin;
use rustpress_plugin::Plugin;

pub struct Signature {
    pub text: String,
}

impl Plugin for Signature {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        "Signature Plugin v0.1 by ferris"
    }

    fn filter_body(&self, body: &mut String) {
        body.push_str("\n-------\n");   // add visual seperator 
        body.push_str(&self.text);
    }
}
```

We created a simple type `Signature` for which we implement the trait `Plugin`. We have to implement the `name()` method and we also override the `filter_body()` method. In our implementation we just add text to the post body. We did not override `filter_title()` because we don't need to.

#### 3. Implement the plugin stack

The CMS has to manage all plugins. I assume that the CMS has a main type `RustPress` that will handle everything. It could look like this (in `rustpress`):

```
extern crate rustpress_plugin;
use rustpress_plugin::Plugin;

pub struct RustPress {
    // ...
    plugins: Vec<Box<Plugin>>,
}

impl RustPress {
    pub fn new() -> RustPress {
        RustPress {
            // ...
            plugins: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    /// Adds a plugin to the stack
    pub fn add_plugin<P: Plugin + 'static>(&mut self, plugin: P) {
        self.plugins.push(Box::new(plugin));
    }

    /// Internal function that prepares a post
    fn serve_post(&self) {
        let mut title = "dummy".to_string();
        let mut body = "dummy body".to_string();

        for p in &self.plugins {
            p.filter_title(&mut title);
            p.filter_body(&mut body);
        }

        // use the finalized title and body now ...
    }

    /// Starts the CMS ...
    pub fn start(&self) {}
}
```

What we are doing here is storing a `Vec` full of boxed plugins (we need to box them, because we want ownership, but traits are unsized). When the CMS then prepare a blog-post, it iterates through all plugins and calls all hooks.

#### 4. Configure and start the CMS

Last step is adding the plugin and starting the CMS (putting it all together). We will do this in the `my-blog` crate:

```
extern crate rustpress;
extern crate rustpress_plugin;
extern crate rustpress_signature;

use rustpress::RustPress;
use rustpress_plugin::Plugin;
use rustpress_signature::Signature;

fn main() {
    let mut rustpress = RustPress::new();

    // add plugin
    let sig = Signature { text: "Ferris loves you <3".into() };
    rustpress.add_plugin(sig);

    rustpress.start();
}
```

---

You also need to add the dependencies to the `Cargo.toml` files. I omitted that because it should be fairly easy.

And note again that this is *one* of many possibilities to create such a system. I hope this example is helpful. You can try it [on playground](http://is.gd/EioW6l), too.

Comment: Let me know if something is not clear enough or if some information is missing!

Comment: Wow finally. Just what I was looking for - what an amazing answer! Thank you so much. Although I already ended up implementing a slightly different architecture before reading your answer. I'm sure though, if I combine my solution with yours, I'll get the best of both and probably a close to optimal architecture, so again, Thanks a alot for taking the time to come up with this quality answer!

Comment: This is an amazing answer, but is it at all possible to automatically add plugins from a config file indicating the list of plugins to be used?