# Idiomatic approach to a Go plugin-based system

Tags: go

I have a Go project I would like to open source but there are certain elements which are not suitable for OSS, e.g. company specific logic etc.

I have conceived of the following approach:

- `interface`s are defined in the core repository.
- Plugins can then be standalone repositories whose `type`s implement the `interface`s defined in core. This allows the plugins to be housed in completely separate modules and therefore have their own CI jobs etc.
- Plugins are compiled into the final binary via symlinks.

This would result in a directory structure something like the following:

```
|- $GOPATH
  |- src
    |- github.com
      |- jabclab
        |- core-system
          |- plugins <-----|
      |- xxx               | 
        |- plugin-a ------>| ln -s
      |- yyy               |  
        |- plugin-b ------>|
```

With an example workflow of:

```
$ go get git@github.com:jabclab/core-system.git
$ go get git@github.com:xxx/plugin-a.git
$ go get git@github.com:yyy/plugin-b.git
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com
$ ln -s ./xxx/plugin-a/*.go ./jabclab/core-system/plugins
$ ln -s ./yyy/plugin-b/*.go ./jabclab/core-system/plugins
$ cd jabclab/core-system
$ go build
```

The one issue I'm not sure about is how to make the types defined in plugins available at runtime in core. I'd rather not use [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) but can't think of a better way at the moment. If I was doing the code in one repo I would use something like:

```
package plugins

type Plugin interface {
  Exec(chan<- string) error
}

var Registry map[string]Plugin

// plugin_a.go
func init() { Registry["plugin_a"] = PluginA{} }

// plugin_b.go
func init() { Registry["plugin_b"] = PluginB{} }
```

In addition to the above question would this overall approach be considered idiomatic?

Comment: Why not do it like `database/sql`? Have the "core" (i.e. `database/sql`), have your "plugins" (e.g. `github.com/lib/pq`), have your "main" which imports the "core" and all "plugins" you want to use. No need for symlinking.

Comment: you can have `go generate` render a main file that imports the plugins, and in each plugin's `init()` function register it in the main repository. The importing, even as `import _ "foo/bar/plugin"` will cause the init func to run on start and register the plugins.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001872/golang-events-eventemitter-dispatcher-for-plugin-architecture/28003144#28003144

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer thanks :-) would this approach allow the external plugins to be compilable standalone? Would they not fail to compile due to the registry variable not being present? If not, I guess the `//go:generate` could either be (a) in the plugin itself, or (b) in the core app which then built further on your `import _ "foo/bar/plugin"` in that it would also generate the addition of the plugin's `type` to the plugin registry.

Comment: This thread on reddit detailed the options for a plugin architecture.
Go lang *will have*, in its further releases a buildmode allowing externally loaded plugin.
https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/3xyaro/plugins_in_golang/

Answer (score 5):

This is one of my favorite issues in Go.  I have an open source project that has to deal with this as well (https://github.com/cpg1111/maestrod), it has pluggable DB and Runtime (Docker, k8s, Mesos, etc) clients.  Prior to the plugin package that is in the master branch of Go (so it should be coming to a stable release soon) I just compiled all of the plugins into the binary and allowed configuration decide which to use.

As of the plugin package, https://tip.golang.org/pkg/plugin/, you can use dynamic linking for plugins, so similar to C's `dlopen()` in its loading, and the behavior of go's plugin package is pretty well outlined in the documentation.

Additionally I recommend taking a look at how Hashicorp addresses this by doing RPC over a local unix socket.  https://github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin

The added benefit of running a plugin as a separate process like Hashicorp's model does, is that you get great stability in the event that the plugin fails but the main process is able to handle that failure.

I should also mention Docker does its plugins in Go similarly, except Docker uses HTTP instead of RPC.  Additionally, a Docker engineer has posted about embedding a Javascript interpreter for dynamic logic in the past http://crosbymichael.com/category/go.html.

The issue I wanted to point out with the sql package's pattern that was mentioned in the comments is that that's not a plugin architecture really, you're still limited to whatever is in your imports, so you could have multiple main.go's but that's not a plugin, the point of a plugin is such that the same program can run either one piece of code or another.  What you have with things like the sql package is flexibility where a separate package determines what DB driver to use.  Nonetheless, you end up modifying code to change what driver you are using.

I want to add, with all of these plugin patterns, aside from the compiling into the same binary and using configuration to choose, each *can* have its own build, test and deployment (i.e. their own CI/CD) but not necessarily.